# how to color the header's bottom line or footer's upper line?

Tags: header-footer, color, titlesec

The title is self-explanatory.

In my document's current state, I get this rendering result after compiling with **XeLaTeX** :

[image: result]

> *Here's a MWE of which packages and commands I use to obtain my current
>   header style :*

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small\sffamily\upshape\color{red}]{
    \headrule
    \sethead{\chaptertitle}{}{Université de la Rochelle}
}


\author{ME}
\title{Bash report}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Matrices de convolution}
\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**What I actually would like is to color "red" the lines created by the header and footer.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`titlesec` defines helper macros to set up the lines, this drops red into the head line

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\setheadrule[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=\z@
    \let\makeheadrule\@empty
  \else
    \def\makeheadrule{{\color{red}\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{#1}}}%
  \fi}

\makeatother


\renewpagestyle{plain}[\small\sffamily\upshape]{
    \headrule
    \sethead{\chaptertitle}{}{Universite de la Rochelle}
}


\author{ME}
\title{Bash report}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Matrices de convolution}
\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The foot rule command is by default

```
\newcommand\setfootrule[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=\z@
    \let\makefootrule\@empty
  \else
    \def\makefootrule{\rule[.7\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \fi}
```

But not apparently used in this MWE so I didn't change it/

Comment: I have an error if I insert the hack that you wrote in my current document state, I get the following compilation error (using XeLaTeX) : ! LaTeX Error: Command \setheadrule already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: I just added **[pagestyles]** to the **\usepackage{titlesec}** inclusion, works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by slightly modifying David's code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\setheadrule[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=\z@
    \let\makeheadrule\@empty
  \else
    \def\makeheadrule{{\color{red}\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{#1}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Using David's code, I had the same [error message reported by vdegenne in his first comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99453/how-to-color-the-headers-bottom-line-or-footers-upper-line/295646#comment214935_99459) (solved by him by adding the `pagestyles` option to the `titlesec` package as said in [his second comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99453/how-to-color-the-headers-bottom-line-or-footers-upper-line#comment214938_99459)). Since their solution did not work for me, I worked out my own by just substituting `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` in Dave's code: this simply redefines the command avoiding any "already defined!" run time error, and produces the sought for graphical output.